# STR_TO_DATE in Update Query using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying insert data into DATETIME column with PDO statement and the result that i got it is NULL

i'm doing this with 2 steps.

First step :

```
$this->params = array_map(function ($val) {


        if (preg_match("/^\d+(-)\d+(-)\d+( \d+(:\d+:\d+))$/", $val, $match)) {

                return "STR_TO_DATE( ? , '%d/%m/%y %G:%i:%s')";

        } else {
            return "?";
        }
```

Second step:

```
try {

        $query = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);

        foreach ($this->values as $key => $val) {

         // exit();   
            $type = is_bool($val)    ? PDO::PARAM_BOOL : PDO::PARAM_STR;
            $type = is_null($val)    ? PDO::PARAM_NULL : PDO::PARAM_STR;
            $type = is_integer($val) ? PDO::PARAM_INT : PDO::PARAM_STR;

            $query->bindValue($key+1, $val, $type);

        }
            var_dump($query );
            $query->execute();
            $this->dbh->commit();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        $this->dbh->rollBack();
        echo $e->getMessage();

    }
```

Query string is :

```
"INSERT INTO `users`
(userFirstName, userLastName, userEmail, userPassword, userRegisterDate, userIP)
 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, STR_TO_DATE( ? , '%d/%m/%y %G:%i:%s'), ?)"
```

all looks good but result that i got in field DATETIME is null.
what i'm doing wrong here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the following pattern for matching:

```
/^\d+(-)\d+(-)\d+( \d+(:\d+:\d+))$/
```

and the string for `STR_TO_DATE` is passed as:

```
%d/%m/%y %G:%i:%s
```

Your regex is set match for dates of the format: `9999-9999-9999 123:456:7890`. This will not be parsed as date for the date-format you're giving. Change the regex as follows:

```
@^\d{1,2}[-]\d{1,2}[-]\d{2,4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}@
```

and the SQL function to:

```
%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s
```

Comment: I think it should be the other way around, as the data has a `-` to separate the date fields, it is the sql that needs to be changed, not the way the date is matched.

Comment: @jeroen Unless the user provides some data, we can't be sure. I'll leave it as it is for now. If OP provides more information, I'll update.

Comment: That's what I thought initially, but as the generated sql contains the replacement, a date was matched once in the `array_map` function.

Comment: it is  giving me 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in data base

Comment: @Viktorino Can you put the `var_dump` of your array in your question?

Comment: i put it and get mutches , but in data base i got 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: whith this regax @^\d{1,2}[-]\d{1,2}[-]\d{2,4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}@ it can't find mutches

Comment: @Viktorino Unless you tell what kind of string you have in teh array, I can't help you.

Comment: string in array  is 07-02-2014 20:50:34

Comment: it is working thank you!! and it is working with this format to   `%d/%m/%y %G:%i:%s`

Comment: @Viktorino It didn't work because MySQL doesn't provide `%G` specifier. Use `%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s`

Comment: like this it's inserting with time `"STR_TO_DATE( ? , '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s %p')";`

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between what you are matching for and what you are adding to your sql in  your `array_map` function.

You are looking for a date separated with `-` signs:

```
/^\d+(-)\d+(-)\d+( \d+(:\d+:\d+))$/
     ^^^   ^^^ here
```

And then you add the following string to the sql:

```
STR_TO_DATE( ? , '%d/%m/%y %G:%i:%s')
                    ^  ^ not a minus-sign...
```

If your input contains the `-` to separate the month from the day, etc., you should use that in the sql as well:

```
STR_TO_DATE( ? , '%d-%m-%y %G:%i:%s')
                    ^  ^ here
```